# PyFile_WriteObject writes too late

Tags: python, printf, cpython

I have more or less this code:

```c
PyObject* py_list(PyObject* obj) {
    printf("py_list: %p, ", obj);
    PyObject* pystdout = PySys_GetObject("stdout");
    PyFile_WriteObject(obj, pystdout, Py_PRINT_RAW);
    printf("\n");
    printf("py_list: %p\n", pystdout);
    if (obj == NULL) {
        return PyList_New(0);
    }
    PyObject* result = PyList_New(1);
    PyList_SetItem(result, 0, obj);
    printf("py_list returns: %p, ", result);
    PyFile_WriteObject(result, pystdout, Py_PRINT_RAW);
    printf("\n");
    return result;
}
```

What I really would like is to replicate `str(obj)` (the Python 2 version of), and then use the result in `printf` call.  I cannot find a sane API for calling something like this.  So, `PyFile_WriteObject` was the closest I could find...  However, instead of writing to `stdout`, it waits until every possible interaction with `stdout` finishes in C, and only then it prints whatever it was supposed to...

I've looked at what Cython generates for code like `print(obj)` or `str(obj)`, and I want to pull my hair out, it's so complex.  All I need, really, is to be able to print out the Python objects for debugging purposes.  I also tried the GDB way, but Python objects are such a mess when you look at them from GDB perspective, it's not really workable either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, instead of writing to `stdout`, [`PyFile_WriteObject`] waits until every possible interaction with `stdout`

You are likely getting bitten by Python-level buffering. A call to `PyObject_CallMethod(pystdout, "flush", "")` would probably fix the issue.

> What I really would like is to replicate `str(obj)` (the Python 2 version of), and then use the result in `printf` call.

The API you're looking for is [`PyObject_Str`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Str) in combination with [`PyUnicode_AsUTF8`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html?highlight=pyunicode_asutf8#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8). This allows things like:

```
printf("py_list returns: %s\n", PyUnicode_AsUTF8(PyObject_Str(result)));
```

That will leak the string returned by `__str__` and crash if `PyObject_Str` raises; the correct version could look like this:

```
void print_obj(PyObject *o) {
    PyObject *o_str = PyObject_Str(o);
    if (!o_str) {
        PyErr_Print();
        return;
    }
    printf("%s\n", PyUnicode_AsUTF8(o_str));
    Py_DECREF(o_str);
}
```

Comment: Even more complications appear to be necessary to do this in Python 3... since nothing is really convertible to strings, only to Unicode arrays. So, I need to first convert to Unicode, then to string, and only then printing.

Comment: @wvxvw No complications whatsoever, `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` gives you UTF-8 which you can pass to `printf` just fine.